# 10Mbs USB to serial communication

Tags: microcontroller, usb, serial, communication

I want to transfer data from a full duplex serial device (TTL) to the PC. The data rate is 10Mbs , i am investigating potential solution. I can add a level converter like max232.
I have 2 questions:

1. ***HARDWARE :***

My first thought is using a dspic33ep series (that supports up to 16Mbs) serial communication to receive data and using DMA and internal USB controller to transfer the PC , using HID or CDC protocol (i have not used USB on this device before) so it will be cumbersome.

In-order not to be reinvent the wheel: Is this doable ? Is there a product ready that can do this ? serial PCI rs232 card (although i haven't found a "MAX232" alternative that works more than 1Mbs) ??

2. ***SOFTWARE :***

I usually use docklight or realterm to capture serial com port data at slower speeds, does the 10Mbs speed create problems on such software , is there a speed limitation for real or emulated Com port ? or is the limitation is the amount of byte per second rather than the speed at which these byte are sent (overflow issues)

*Forgive me if the question sounds noob and I am also open to alternatives that are simple and time saving on this project.*

Comment: USB 3.2 can transfer data at up to 10 Gbit/s. Ethernet/USB adapter may transfer in that range also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to reinvent the wheel, why not use one of the FTDI products, like the [FT2232H](http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/ICs/FT2232H.htm)

Comment: good call hardware wise ( when i searched FTDI before , i missed this one , FT232R and FT2232D are limited to 3Mbs). just a quick question , do you know if software or hardware handshaking should be used at such speeds or it doesnot matter?

Comment: The chip lists handshaking capabilities, and the datasheet doesn't mention a handshaking speed limit.  Can't speak to your TTL device, but that would seem to be independent of your hardware approach.

Comment: Check the datasheet for FT2232H's FIFO size. At 10Mbps a simple USB hiccup would probably fill them, so you will likely want hardware handshaking here to prevent fifo overflows.

Comment: @Turbo J , thanks for the insight on hardware handshaking , my device also supports them (after checking FT232H which also support 10Mbs has 1k fifo , ft2232 has 4k fifo) .  Anybody has answer on part 2 of the question , regarding the software ?